# Creating proper Certificate in non-dev mode

Tags: corda

I want to create a new Node for my corda network. Can you help me with correct steps for generating a proper Certificate Key for a new node in non-dev Mode.

Comment: Hi, wer you able to create a netwokr ? I want to understand the same process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a new node for an existing non-dev network, you need to register with the network's certificate signing authority (or *doorman*) to obtain a valid identity for the zone using the following command:

```
java -jar corda.jar --initial-registration --network-root-truststore-password <trust store password>
```

As part of this process, the node will automatically generate a new public/private keypair. You do not need to generate this keypair yourself.

Before you can register, you must first have received the trust store file containing the root certificate from the zone operator. By default the trust store file is expected to be in the location `certificates/network-root-truststore.jks`. This can be overridden with the additional `--network-root-truststore` flag.